# Bootable USB flash drive doesn't seem to boot

Tags: boot

I want to wipe my hard disk on my computer with a disk wiper included in [Ultimate Boot CD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/). I therefore prepared an USB flash drive to boot from. I tested on another laptop and it can boot the **Ultimate Boot CD**.

On [my computer](https://www.medion.com/de/service/product-detail/10019633) I can select the boot device and I select the USB flash drive:

[image]

However, the computer continues to boot windows.

Why is this the case? How can I boot from the USB flash drive?

**EDIT:**
For reference, I attached the relevant pictures of my BIOS:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That usually happens when the USB fails to boot, as the motherboard firmware then looks for the next bootloader [Windows] and tries to then boot that.

Comment: And why could this be the case? On another laptop, I can boot from the usb stick.

Comment: Whatever you think you need to use from the ANCIENT Ultimate Boot CD you have in much newer and UEFI compatible tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Ultimate Boot CD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html) download page states:

*Please note that UBCD currently does not support UEFI Boot. If you have a UEFI machine, please remember to turn on CSM Boot in your BIOS.*

Judging from your screenshot, your machine is configured to only boot UEFI and is therefore unable to boot Ultimate Boot CD.

You need to enable CSM (if supported).

Your other system where it works is either a Legacy (Non-UEFI) system, or it has CSM enabled.

Comment: Thank you! I attached the relevant screenshots from my BIOS. If I understand your answer correctly, because I have no CSM there is no way to boot ultimate boot cd.

Comment: Check the 'Advanced' menu of your BIOS - CSM can usually be found in there. As your system appears to be from 2014, it most probably supports CSM.

Comment: @MartinBöschen Your motherboard may not have an option for CSM [Legacy] Mode, as it's being phased out since it serves hardly any purpose at this point. The sole purpose of [CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#CSM_booting) was to allow the booting of distros that didn't yet support EFI boot circa <2017 _(Windows has supported EFI boot since Win7, all distros support as of 2017)_; only reason for needing CSM Mode today is to boot into Legacy OPROMs and motherboard OEMs, such as Intel, began shipping motherboards within the last few years without CSM Mode, which will become the norm

Comment: Thanks, I managed to boot. In my bios, I went to the 'Advanced' menu, the selected 'Win7' for 'OS Select' and that enabled CSM.